# How to sort by name?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have records. A record has the following format:

```
<client host> - - [<timestamp with timezone>] <HTTP-request line (type, URL, version)> <Code of HTTP-response> <Number of sent bytes or '-', if the response is empty> <Referer string ('-'  means direct request without referer)> <Client info (browser, application)>
```

For example these 5 lines:

```
20158147070.user.veloxzone.com.br - - [29/Oct/2006:06:59:18 -0700] "GET /example/.comments 
HTTP/1.1" 404 293 "http://www.example.org/example/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; 
Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
20158147070.user.veloxzone.com.br - - [29/Oct/2006:06:59:18 -0700] "GET /example/.comments 
HTTP/1.1" 404 293 "http://www.example.org/example/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; 
Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
adorno.ub.uni-duesseldorf.de - - [10/Oct/2006:06:59:37 -0700] "GET /example/.comments 
HTTP/1.0" 404 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WinNT4.0; de-DE; rv:1.0.2) Gecko/20030208 
Netscape/7.02"
nat240.ariba.com - - [29/Oct/2006:07:40:47 -0700] "GET //example/example.atom' HTTP/1.1" 304 
298 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 
Thunderbird/1.5.0.7"
nat240.ariba.com - - [31/Oct/2006:07:10:47 -0700] "GET /example/example.atom' HTTP/1.1" 304 
297 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 
Thunderbird/1.5.0.7"
```

I need to sort it by url name, regardless of the rest of the line.

I used awk to find 404 errors and now I need sort

```
cat log.txt | gawk '$9=="404"' | gawk '{print $7 , $9}' |  uniq -c | sort -r
```

but I have this :

```
2 /example/.comments 404
1 /example/.comments 404
```

I need it like this :

```
3 /example/.comments 404
```

..........

```
1. /example/.comments - 28 - 32.2%
2. /example/example.atom.xml - 9 - 10.3%
3. /example/When/200x/2003/04/10/-big/Concorde.jpg - 8 - 9.2%
4. /example/When/200x/2006/03/30/-big/IMG_4613.jpg - 7 - 8.0%
5. /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/guild-2.jpg - 6 - 6.9%
6. /example/Patti-Smith.png - 5 - 5.7%
7. /example/IMGP4289-2.png - 5 - 5.7%
8. /example/IMGP4287.png - 5 - 5.7%
9. /example/Image-Search-Mystery.png - 5 - 5.7%
10. /example/Horses.png - 5 - 5.7%
11. /example/When/200x/2004/02/27/-big/Unreal.png - 4 - 4.6%
```

The format is: a list or counter, followed by the name urls, followed by the unique number of them, followed by their percentage of all 404 errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use `sort` before using `uniq` command.
The way `uniq` works is that it only counts duplicates if they are lined one after another, if you have the same line several lines after some different lines that line won't be counted to previous duplicates.

You should always use `sort` and pipe to `uniq -c` to get the exact count of same lines.

Also, since the first column will be a number of counts you should use `sort -n` if you want them sorted out by occurrence number.

You can also remove the first cat and do awk on the file directly and not the `cat` output.

You should use something likes this:

```
gawk '$9=="404"' log.txt | gawk '{print $7 , $9}' |  sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

You can also use `sort -k` to sort by a second column if you don't want to sort by count number.

```
gawk '$9=="404"' log.txt | gawk '{print $7 , $9}' |  sort | uniq -c | sort -k 2
```

If you don't need to count number of lines you can just use sort -u to get unique lines, and you can join the two awk pipes in one.

```
gawk '$9=="404" {print $7 , $9}' log.txt | sort -u
```

If you would want to sort by number of occurences and count all the 404 in one command you would need to do everything inside awk with something like this:

```
gawk '{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"} $9=="404" {count_url[$7]++} {count_404[$9]++} END {for(url in count_url) print count_url[url],url;print "number of 404 errors: "count_404[404];}' log.txt
```

Comment: Note that `sort` has `-u`nique included as option.

Comment: it won't count the number of same lines, he needs uniq -c if he wants to count the lines

Comment: how can i put the number of lines after name ?) like /example/.comments 3 . And one more question, how to make counter of lines? like 1. /example/.comments 3 |(new line) 2. and so on

Comment: What exactly do you mean by counter of lines, can you edit your question with the exact result you would want to get?